# Is there a better way than a grid to line up controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, grid, stackpanel

I am using a grid by the definition of appropriateness defined in this question [Grid vs Stackpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452045/wpf-grid-vs-stackpanel). However when working with grids you have to define the controls position inside them explicitly in the grid. This becomes a pain when having to reorder controls or when adding a new control to the grid. With the code provided as an example, is there a way to get the rows and columns for the text and text boxes to line up while being easy to modify or expand later?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Value One:"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOne"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Value Two:"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxTwo"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Value Three:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxThree" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a custom control I use that makes it extremely easy to do this, but before I created it I generally used this sort of thing:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ColumnsTemplate" TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header" />
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ItemsControl ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnsTemplate}">
  <HeaderedContentControl Header="Value One:">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOne" />
  </HeaderedContentControl>
  <HeaderedContentControl Header="Value Two:">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxTwo" />
  </HeaderedContentControl>
  ...
</ItemsControl>
```

This allows easy add/remove of items from the ItemsControl, or better yet, data binding.

If you prefer auto-sizing on the grid rather than star sizing (3* and 7*) you can use a shared sizing scope by setting `IsSharedSizeScope` on the `ItemsControl` and `SharedSizeGroup` on the first `ColumnDefinition`.

Another option is `GridView`, but I find it more difficult to use for this purpose.

Comment: That is the exact pattern I was looking for and you showed me ControlTemplate as well, Thanks.

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work (any longer). The message is "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.DataTemplate".