# What's the best way to create a dense input form in WPF/Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Given that you're creating a **User Control** in WPF that will be displayed on different screen resolutions, what's the best way to layout a dense collection of "input form" elements?

For example, labels, textboxes for text, dropdowns, group boxes, etc.

Do you create a master "grid" and use StackPanels and WrapPanels like crazy? What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of doing it is like you described - master Grid with tons of StackPanels and Grid.Row="" statements. However you might try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452045/wpf-grid-vs-stackpanel) and the top answer. The DockPanel looks promising, and I think next time I make a dense input form, I'll try using it.

A really concise tutorial can be found [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html).

Comment: Most of my UI's use combinations of these panels, nested in a hierarchy. A GridPanel maybe on the outside, with individual cells containing StackPanels or other.