# What is the intended way to make a label and text box side by side in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'll often use this:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label>Username:</Label>
    <TextBox />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label>Password:</Label>
    <PasswordBox />
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But it is such a common scenario, I feel like there is a way with less markup.

Also, is there a performance impact of using so many stack panels?

Comment: It's XML-based - it's supposed to be excessively verbose ;-)

Comment: The markup you've shown is paltry compared to the Visual Studio or Expression Blend generated markup - try positioning your controls using the designer (i.e. drag them around). You'll see what I mean, and then probably never want to use the designer again for layout. What you have there shouldn't be a problem at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two primary ways to do this, **StackPanels** and **Grid Definitions**, and `Grid` does not provide any less markup than `StackPanel`. I personally like to use **Grid Definitions** a lot more. They take awhile to get use to, and every now and then I still use a `StackPanel`, but overall they feel a lot cleaner when you get use to them. [Here is a great tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) on how to use them.

A reference that might also help is [WPF Grid Vs. StackPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452045/wpf-grid-vs-stackpanel).

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why, but I've become very fond of `DockPanel`'s, and I use them for the scenario you've described.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label Content="Username:"/>
    <TextBox Text="Some Text"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The longhand (and equivalent version, since the default dock position is left):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Username:"/>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="Some Text"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Also, it has a property `LastChildFill` which is `true` by default, making the last child added to it fill the remaining space (I like this feature). So, in the above examples, the `TextBox` will fill the remaining available horizontal space. (You can turn it off easily by switching it to false)

Hope that helps!!

[`DockPanel` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I mostly prefer `Grid` if large number of labels and textboxes needs to be present in the form, like data entry or property grid kind of controls. Grid provides much more power to control the `width`/`height` of rows columns and changing the `width`/`height` value at one place will affect all the rows.

One more benefit of using `Grid` is alignment, all labels and textboxes(or other controls) will be aligned correctly. In case of `Stackpanel` or `Dockpanel` you will have to explicitly set the wdth to each label to align them properly.

You can also use `GridSplitter` in Grid which can be very useful in PropertGrid kind of controls.

In case only one or two such rows are needed and alignment is not a concern you can go ahead with `Dockpanel` or `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `UniformGrid` will work wonders with relatively small amount of code. I sort of re-discovered it recently and often works quite well for simple scenarios where you have a lot of textboxes and labels.

```
  <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="6"  >
                        <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="Location 1" />
                        <TextBlock>Latitude (°)</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="20.4" />
                        <TextBlock>Longitude (°)</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="10.5" />
                        <TextBlock>X error (°)</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="0.5" />
                        <TextBlock>Y error (°)</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="1.2" />
                        <TextBlock>Angle (°)</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Text="10.4" />
   </UniformGrid>
```