# WPF control positioning problem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i am learning WPF here is my XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Height="300"
    Width="634">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="35"
            Width="89"
            Name="p1">Hello</Button>
    <Border CornerRadius="5"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Height="35"
            Width="254"
            Margin="91,192,150,79">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Height="35"
                 Width="250"
                 Name="txtContents" />
    </Border>
    <Button Height="23"
            Name="button1"
            Width="75">Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

button textbox is showing but the problem is I am not being able to drag the control to another location. how to fix it. please help. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'able to drag the control to another locaiton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you can't drag the `Button` controls to different locations, it's because they're contained within a `StackPanel` - stacking them one on top of each other.

If you change that `StackPanel` to be a `Grid`, you'd have the ability to drag it around in a canvas-like manner.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Height="300"
    Width="634">
<Grid>
    <Button Height="35"
            Width="89"
            Name="p1">Hello</Button>
    <Border CornerRadius="5"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Height="35"
            Width="254"
            Margin="91,192,150,79">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Height="35"
                 Width="250"
                 Name="txtContents" />
    </Border>
    <Button Height="23"
            Name="button1"
            Width="75">Button</Button>
</Grid>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452045/wpf-grid-vs-stackpanel) may shed some light on where to use `Grid`s and `StackPanel`s.

Answer (score 1):

If by "able to drag the control to another location" you are talking about repositioning the control using Expression Blend or the Visual Studio Designer you need to change the StackPanel to a Grid

So it would become-

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Height="300"
    Width="634">
<Grid>
    <Button Height="35"
            Width="89"
            Name="p1">Hello</Button>
    <Border CornerRadius="5"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Height="35"
            Width="254"
            Margin="91,192,150,79">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Height="35"
                 Width="250"
                 Name="txtContents" />
    </Border>
    <Button Height="23"
            Name="button1"
            Width="75">Button</Button>
</Grid>
```